# Rewrite URL's to Subdomain in NGINX

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have several url's that I would like to rewrite in NGINX
for example:

```
From: app.example.com/calendar
To: calendar.example.com
```

Or

```
From: app.example.com/meetings
To: meetings.example.com
```

I would still like to keep the `app.example.com` so it's not being removed from the redirect, but just create subdomains for certain URLs.

How can I do this in NGINX conf file?
All the best.

Comment: Is the `calendar` subdomain pointing to a different server/service?

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect Subdomain to Folder in NGINX**

Just add the following location block in your server configuration, inside server block, above the `location /`  block.

```
location ^~ /calendar {
    rewrite ^/calendar/?(.*)$ https://calendar.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

In the above code replace `blog.example.com` with your subdomain, and `/calendar` with your subdirectory. The above location block will listen to all requests sent to `example.com/calendar`. It redirects all those requests to `calendar.example.com` subdomain of your website. `$1` is the URL stub after subfolder in requested URL. We add `permanent` keyword at the end of `rewrite` directive to cause a permanent redirect.

So it will permanently redirect subfolder to subdomain along with URL string.

Comment: The OP is not wanting an _external_ redirect, like they say in the question: "I would still like to keep the `app.example.com` so it's not being removed from the redirect" and they have tagged the question `nginx-reverse-proxy`. (Where did "blog" come from?)